# Python decision tree almost always chosing the same class

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, tree

I'm trying to implement a Decision Tree algorithm in Python and I'm having some problems. I took the example for the implementation:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-decision-tree-algorithm-scratch-python/

My classes are discrete classes and my data looks like the following:

```
x1             x2                y 
0.247224       0.441384          3.0
0.283196       0.212166          5.0
0.374300       0.151103          6.0
0.181024       0.232722          4.0
0.376329       0.176915          6.0
0.122801       0.583578          1.0
...            ...               ...
0.905578       0.117259          8.0
0.931590       0.111953          8.0
```

where the 2 attributes are normalized from 0 to 1, and the 1st attribute goes up as the class number goes up and the 2nd attribute goes down as the class number goes up. 
The dataset contains around 2000 records.

I implemented the algorithm linked above that uses a Gini index to evaluate splits, and I'm having unexpected results.

When the tree is created and I try to compare with a dataset, my predicted value is almost always the class '4' (around 95% of the time).

I'm testing with a max tree depth of 20 and a minimum size of 20, and I tried many settings and they would all give the same results of almost always predicting 4.

When I'm printing the tree with the print_tree function of the tutorial, it is giving me this:

```
[X2 < 0.030]
 [8.0]
 [X1 < 0.932]
  [X1 < 0.001]
   [2.0]
   [X1 < 0.021]
    [X1 < 0.018]
     [1.0]
     [1.0]
    [X2 < 0.982]
     [X1 < 0.022]
      [3.0]
      [X1 < 0.025]
       [2.0]
       [X1 < 0.028]
        [1.0]
        [X1 < 0.028]
         [2.0]
         [X1 < 0.028]
          [3.0]
          [X1 < 0.029]
           [1.0]
           [X1 < 0.029]
            [2.0]
            [X1 < 0.032]
             [1.0]
             [X1 < 0.034]
              [2.0]
              [X1 < 0.035]
               [1.0]
               [X1 < 0.036]
                [2.0]
                [X1 < 0.037]
                 [1.0]
                 [X2 < 0.825]
                  [X2 < 0.758]
                   [X2 < 0.718]
                    [4.0]
                    [3.0]
                   [2.0]
                  [3.0]
     [1.0]
  [8.0]
```

We can clearly see something wrong is happening in the tree, and that it almost always reaches the bottom-case (4).

I'm not looking for people to give me a solution, I just want to understand if I understand correctly the algorithm and if it can apply with my data.

Thanks!

Comment: On what data do you train the tree and what is the data for testing. Also, how many class 4 observations do you have on each set? Your tree might overfit your training data, it's very common for decision trees. If that's the case you can try [random forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) or decrease the two parameters you mentioned.

Comment: @Guys I have a total of around 3200 records which I split 2/3 so 2133 training and 1066 test. And the proportion of classes is as follow: ( 4.0: 768, 5.0: 759, 6.0: 596,  3.0: 532, 2.0: 331, 1.0: 159, 8.0: 50, 7.0: 33). What do you mean by "decreasing" the two parameters? Thanks

Comment: You can try to decrease the max tree size for example. 20 sounds too high for you data. Anyway, decision trees doesn't necessarily fit your data. if you are interest in learning you could start with well tested datasets such as Iris.

Comment: @Guys Ok thank you I'll try with different parameters, and try with the Iris dataset for practice